# Sync horizontal scroll between two Tabulator tables (Tabulator 5)

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Since the release of Tabulator 5.0 the events and callbacks have been changed.
For the previous releases there was a solution to sync scrolling between two Tabulator tables (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/203)

My problem is now that these callbacks/events do not exist anymore in Tabulator 5, but I would like to have a similar solution.

I do have two Tabulator 5 tables and do want to sync horizontal scrolling. When I scroll one table the other one should do the same scroll. Both tables do have the same column definition.

Does anyone know how I could solve this in Tabulator 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Scroll Horizontal event. The code would be:

```
table1.on('scrollHorizontal',function(left,dir){
  $(".tabulator-tableholder","#table2").scrollLeft(left)
});

table2.on('scrollHorizontal',function(left,dir){
      $(".tabulator-tableholder","#table1").scrollLeft(left)
});
```

For example:

```js
var tabledata = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Oli Bob",
  age: "12",
  col: "red",
  dob: ""
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Mary May",
  age: "1",
  col: "blue",
  dob: "14/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Christine Lobowski",
  age: "42",
  col: "green",
  dob: "22/05/1982"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Brendon Philips",
  age: "125",
  col: "orange",
  dob: "01/08/1980"
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Margret Marmajuke",
  age: "16",
  col: "yellow",
  dob: "31/01/1999"
}];
var table1 = new Tabulator("#table1", {
  height: 150,
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    hozAlign: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    hozAlign: "center"
  }, {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    hozAlign: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    hozAlign: "center"
  }]
});
var table2 = new Tabulator("#table2", {
  height: 150,
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    hozAlign: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    hozAlign: "center"
  }, {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 150
  }, {
    title: "Age",
    field: "age",
    hozAlign: "left",
    formatter: "progress"
  }, {
    title: "Favourite Color",
    field: "col"
  }, {
    title: "Date Of Birth",
    field: "dob",
    sorter: "date",
    hozAlign: "center"
  }]
});

table1.on("scrollHorizontal", function(left, dir) {
  $(".tabulator-tableholder", "#table2").scrollLeft(left)
});
table1.on("scrollVertical", function(top, dir) {
  $(".tabulator-tableholder", "#table2").scrollTop(top)
});
table2.on("scrollHorizontal", function(left, dir) {
  $(".tabulator-tableholder", "#table1").scrollLeft(left)
});
table2.on("scrollVertical", function(top, dir) {
  $(".tabulator-tableholder", "#table1").scrollTop(top)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.1.7/css/tabulator_bootstrap3.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.1.7/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:48%;display:inline-block;">
  <div id="table1"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:48%;display:inline-block;">
  <div id="table2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed! I totally missed the fact that i can select the HTML-element and use the scrollLeft-method!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tabulator's [`scrollHorizontal`](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/events#scrolling) event to sync horizontal scrolling between two tables. For example:

```
table1.on("scrollHorizontal", (left) => {
  document.querySelector("#table2 .tabulator-tableholder").scrollLeft = left
})

table2.on("scrollHorizontal", (left) => {
  document.querySelector("#table1 .tabulator-tableholder").scrollLeft = left
})
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/izmirli/pen/LYeNpYO

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed! I totally missed the fact that i can select the HTML-element and use the scrollLeft-method